# why when calling font.render () does the program return an error?

Tags: python, pygame

i am trying to learn some of the basics of pygame via the following pdf: https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pygame/latest/pygame.pdf
and I stopped on page 29 where it shows me that the Rect class defines 4 cornerpoints, 4 mid points and 1 centerpoint. but when I start the program it gives me an error saying No module named 'rect' and if i delete it says **font** is not defined what should I add to make it work correctly?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from rect import *

def draw_point(text, pos):
    img = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED, pos, 3)
    screen.blit(img, pos)

pygame.init()

GRAY = (125, 125, 125)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 240))

rect = Rect(50, 40, 250, 80)
pts = ('topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright', 'midtop', 'midright', 'midbottom', 'midleft', 'center')

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    
    screen.fill(GRAY)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, rect, 4)
    
    for pt in pts:
        draw_point(pt, eval('rect.'+pt))
    
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Where do you define `font`?

Comment: Read chapter 5, it shows how to assign `font`.

Comment: You have missed to create a [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) object. e.g. `pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)`. I recommend to read the document carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep reading that book; The section `3.9 The common code` contains the definition of `rect.py`:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint

width = 500
height = 200

RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
MAGENTA = (255, 0, 255)
CYAN = (0, 255, 255)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GRAY = (150, 150, 150)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

dir = {K_LEFT: (-5, 0), K_RIGHT: (5, 0), K_UP: (0, -5), K_DOWN: (0, 5)}

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)
running = True
```

Once you create that file you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must define a font

for example:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 35)

game_over_text = "Press Space to Start"
game_over_label = font.render(game_over_text, 1, (255,255,255))
window.blit(game_over_label, (WIDTH-550, HEIGHT-400))
```